# Facebook language not changed to spanish when system language is changed in android

Tags: android

Facebook language not changed to spanish when system language is changed to spanish in android device when I try to launch facebook from my app. It still remains in English rather than spansih.

Comment: Please explain what this has to do with programming.

Comment: I am trying to launch the facebook through my app. Is there a way in which  I could send current language to facebook

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in which I could send current language to facebook

Probably not.

Android applications usually determine their language from the OS automatically. A few might play games with custom `Locale` settings to override what strings they use, based upon some user language selection within the app itself. Few, if any, apps will offer some sort of API for third-party developers to tell them what language to use.

You are welcome to contact Facebook and ask them if their app has such an API.